# How to reverse text on Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, text

When I enter data in a Google Spreadsheets cell, I would like the text to reverse itself.

For instance, I would like to put in a cell `My text` and get it converted to `txet yM`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to install and use a script to do it.

1. In your spreadsheet, select **Tools** → **Script Gallery** → **Insert...**.
2. Search for `reverse`. You should see String.reverse().
3. Click **Install**, then **Authorize**.
4. Close the Script Gallery.

To use the script, type `=REVERSE(A1)` where A1 is the cell with the text you want to reverse.

---

If you are using the new Google Sheets, the Script Gallery is not available. You will need to create your own custom function.

1. Select **Tools** → **Script editor...**
2. Select **Blank project**
3. Replace the code with:

   ```
   /**
    * Reverses the input text.
    *
    * @param {string} input The text to reverse.
    * @return The input text reversed.
    * @customfunction
    */
   function REVERSE(string) {
     if (typeof string != 'string') {
       return null;
     }
     return string.split('').reverse().join('');
   }
   ```
4. Save, return to your spreadsheet, and use `=REVERSE(A1)` as described above.

Comment: jep works fine - only running on 10000-s of lines of data gives an error because invoked too often

Comment: @snh_nl see my answer below that doesn't require usage of a script (=no invoked too often error)

Answer (score 12):

As Ben Collins writes in [his Blog](https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/reverse-text/) you can extract all letters and concatenate them in reverse order using an ArrayFormula **without any script**:

Use `=ArrayFormula(concatenate(MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+1,1))` to reverse the content of `A1`.

This will not trigger your Google apps limits as easily as the script solution.

---

[image: example]
[-> example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p5txjfMfOVmtJH7vGMGZCu16n1ost0g3A4RYVGvsslg/edit#gid=0)